# How to scrape a word from img, alt tag

Tags: python, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

```
HTMLCode
```

< div class="movieLogo"

img alt="1 Million" src="https://wwwimage-us.pplus.com/base/files/movie/20/39/93/1mhn.png"
< /div

I have tried the below xpath's to call "1 Million" from img tag.

1. TITLE = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="movieLogo"][1]').text.strip()
2. TITLE = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class=".movieLogo"]').text.strip()
3. TITLE = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="hero-content-slider"]/div[1]/li/div/div[2]/h1/div').text.strip()

Tried full xpath too
But still i didnt get output "1 Million"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the lack of information, hard to give you a proper answer.

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for the text "*1 Million*", which is the text of the attribute "*alt*" and **NOT** from "*@class="movieLogo*".

So let's try this code below:

(**!!** *find_element_by_* commands are deprecated in the latest Selenium Python libraries. **!!**)

```
title = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="movieLogo"]').get_attribute('alt')
```

Or

```
title = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="movieLogo"]').get_attribute('alt')
```

If it doesn't work, come back with more information: link, more HTML code...

We can't really help you with only one line of HTML code.

Comment: I FOund the solution thanks everyone